# Configuring 2 database in mybatis + springs

Tags: database, spring, mybatis

I have an existing setup of mybatis + springs for working with Oracle DB. I have a set of java mapper interfaces, a set of corresponding mapper xmls (each having reference to their corresponding java mapper). I need to setup support for MSSQL also, but finding it hard to do that. I have created a separate set of xmls (specific to queries of MSSQL) in com/mycomp/mob/db/mappers/mssql.

Below is the extract of my applicationConext.xml (Here DBDataSource is an internal class which reads a config files to get all DB details).

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="com.mycomp.mob.core.db.DBDataSource">
    <constructor-arg index="0" name="dbAlias" value="mob" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" name="cfgSection" value="primary" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.mycomp.mob.db.mappers.oracle" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.mycomp.mob.db.mappers.oracle" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Below is part of mybatis-config.xml (here ${} params are replaced using the earlier DBDatasource)

```
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.mycomp.mob.db.model" />
    </typeAliases>
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="${driver}" />
                <property name="url" value="${url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${password}" />
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="com/mycomp/mob/db/mappers/oracle/tenant.xml" />
        <mapper resource="com/mycomp/mob/db/mappers/oracle/functionenty.xml" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

com.mycomp.mob.db.model contains POJO for tenant and functionentry.
Usage is as below :

```
      ITenantMapper mappper = sqlSessionFactory.openSession().getMapper(ItenantMapper.class)
      Tenant t = mapper.getTenant();
```

Now at a time only one DB (which is configured as primary in DB config file) will be used. So how to make sure that XML corresponding to that particular DB is invoked by the java mapper interface.
Also need to know can I configure same java mapper class name inside the mapper xmls of mssql ?
Is the flow used correct or I need to change the flow for supporting multiple databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two datasources and two SessionFactories in spring one for Oracle another for MSSQL.

Comment: Fine.. but then how will the runtime code determine which set to be called.. there has to be some place where a condition determines the DB to be used and based on that the accurate sessionfactory to be called ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have two sqlSessionFactories. In your code you just use the one you need in particular use case to open session. You probably inject sessionFactory to some other beans. Inject by name the session factory you need and use it.